# Ios Simulator not launching react native app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

[image: Screen Capture]

Hey , like you see in the picture when i am try to launch my react native app by doing `react-native run-ios` my terminal just block on the info Building (using "xcodebuild ...)

I also tried to run directly from Xcode but Xcode not responding when i open the xCode file ...

I am on Mac Os Catalina 10.15.2 and Xcode 10.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You may need a newer version of Xcode. Xcode 11.3 added Catalina support.